# Jupyterlab: turn on tab completion for text editor as in Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

In Jupyterlab, there is a text editor that we can open `.py` files, is it possible to also turn on tab completion, just like how it works in Notebook ?

Answer (score 7):

By now, tab completion in the text editor of jupyter lab has been implemented in [this pull request](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/5049) (see also discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4487)). However, for it to be working you need to open a console for the editor (right click in the editor window and select *Create Console for Editor*).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is currently an open issue. https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/1276

Answer (score 1):

The package [jupyterlab-lsp](https://github.com/jupyter-lsp/jupyterlab-lsp) now provides tab completion in the text editor. You need can install it from pip or conda, along with a language server for Python:

```
pip install jupyter-lsp
pip install jedi-language-server
```

I also needed to enable the server side extension:

```
jupyter server extension enable --user --py jupyter_lsp
```

And enabled `@krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp` and `@krassowski/completion-theme` via JupyterLab's extension GUI (the puzzle piece on the right hand side). Then I restarted JupyterLab, and completion worked (with <kbd>Tab</kbd>). I am not sure if all these steps are neccessary, it might depend on your environment.